# Redirect Error: Wordpress + Let's Encrypt (Certbot) + SSL only + non-www

Tags: apache, ssl, mod-rewrite, https, url-rewriting

**Note:** See the updates at the end of this post. For the final (working) conf-files see update 4 at the end of this post or the post which I marked as the solution.

I badly configured my apache conf-files and now I'm getting a redirect error (ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS). I want to redirect everything to HTTPS (non-www). I already tried to add this to the wp-config.php regarding [this tips](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-error-too-many-redirects-issue-in-wordpress/), but that didn't solve the problem:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://d0main.xyz');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://d0main.xyz');
```

and I tried to add

```
define('WP_HOME','https://d0main.xyz');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://d0main.xyz');
```

### Here are my Apache files:

**d0main.xyz.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName d0main.xyz
ServerAlias www.d0main.xyz
ServerAdmin contact@d0main.xyz
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
Redirect permanent / https://d0main.xyz

<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
# changed from None to FileInfo
AllowOverride FileInfo
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**d0main.xyz-le-ssl.conf**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>

ServerName d0main.xyz
ServerAlias www.d0main.xyz
ServerAdmin d0main@d0main.xyz
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
Redirect permanent / https://d0main.xyz

<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
# changed from None to FileInfo
AllowOverride FileInfo
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

RewriteEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/d0main.xyz/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/d0main.xyz/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>

</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
```

**Update 1**: I solved the redirection error by removing `Redirect permanent / https://d0main.xyz` in my `d0main.xyz-le-ssl.conf`, but now there is a `/` missing at the end of the URL. Graphic URL's for example are now `https://d0main.xyzwp-content/image.jpg`

**Update 2**: This is getting more weird. I changed the line `Redirect permanent / https://d0main.xyz` to `Redirect permanent / https://d0main.xyz\/` in my `d0main.xyz.conf`. Now some images have two slashes (and work) `https://d0main.xyz//wp-content/uploads/2016/10/logo-5.png`, while other images still have no slash in their URL: `https://d0main.xyzwp-content/uploads/2016/10/image2.png`

**Update 3**: I forgot to post my *.htaccess*

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

### Update 4: My final (working) conf-files:

**d0main.xyz.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName d0main.xyz
ServerAlias www.d0main.xyz
ServerAdmin contact@d0main.xyz
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
Redirect permanent / https://d0main.xyz/

<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
# changed from None to FileInfo
AllowOverride FileInfo
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**d0main.xyz-le-ssl.conf**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>

ServerName delegatex.xyz
ServerAlias www.delegatex.xyz
ServerAdmin delegatexyz@gmail.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
# changed from None to FileInfo
AllowOverride FileInfo
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

RewriteEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/delegatex.xyz/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/delegatex.xyz/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

</VirtualHost>

</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to escape the forward slash, so instead of `Redirect permanent / https://d0main.xyz\/` you should just have `Redirect permanent / https://d0main.xyz/`. But when redirecting (and ProxyPassing) you should *always* match trailing slashes.

Instead of the following lines.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

You should have a SSL vhost for www.d0main.xyz and jsut do `Redirect / https://d0main.xyz/`

If you are still getting the double slashes it looks like the reason must be elsewhere. DO you have any htaccess files?

Comment: Yes, I have a .htaccess to remove the `index.php` within the permalinks of Wordpress. This is how it looks:

`# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress`

Will post it as *Update 3* in my first post.

Comment: OK, well that doesn't look like it will change anything. So just try removing the backslash from your redirect. See if that fixes things. Just make sure any redirect you have has matching trailing slashes on both the first and second argument,

Comment: Thanks. It works now. Will add my final Apache conf-files in **Update 4**.